# Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] but not ng-route

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have looked at several questions on this already and for the life of me, I can't figure this one out. I'm not using `ng-route` and I'm certain its getting the file I'm trying to learn some basic js, so I have been doing a couple of tutorials. One is throwing this error:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.10/$injector/modulerr?p0=gemStore&p1=Error%…gleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.10%2Fangular.min.js%3A17%3A350)

EDITED

Here's my code:
HTML

```
//index.html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="gemStore">
  <head>
    <title>myTestApp</title>
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js" />
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="StoreController as store">
    <div ng-repeat="product in store.products" ng-hide="store.product.soldOut">
        <h1>{{store.product.name}}</h1>
        <h1>{{store.product.price}}</h1>
        <h1>{{store.product.desc}}</h1>
        <button ng-show="store.product.canPurchase">Add To Cart</button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
    var app = angular.module('gemStore', []);
    app.controller('StoreController', function() {
        this.products = gems;
    });
    var gems = [
        {
            name: 'Gem',
            price: 2.95,
            desc: '. . .',
            canPurchase = false,
            soldOut = true,
        },
        {
            name: 'Gem2',
            price: 3.95,
            desc: '. . .',
            canPurchase = false,
            soldOut = true,
        }
    ]
```

Comment: Why are you using an IIFE? It's unnecessary and the syntax is wrong. You're missing the actual call with ()

Comment: Also, you have a syntax error in your html. The ng-repeat attribute in your div

Comment: Sorry, its probably an old tutorial. Thank you for catching the syntax error. The error is still there though, so I must have made another mistake.

Comment: Have you read my first comment?

Comment: Where is it that im missing the ()? Sorry, like I said, I'm just trying to learn.

Comment: Right at the end. The last line should be `})();`

Comment: Do you mind opening up a chat? I really appreciate your help. I got rid of the IIFE but still have the error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107288/discussion-between-mparnisari-and-speed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of errors/suggestions:

- I don't know if the `div ng-controller="StoreController as store"` syntax is correct or not, but it's not necessary. You can just write `div ng-controller="StoreController"`
- You need to have at least one product with `soldOut = true` in order to see something :)
- There was an error in the way you declared your gems. The correct way to declare an object literal is `var gem = {soldOut: true}`, not `var gem = {soldOut = true}`.
- You don't need to wrap your Angular code with an IIFE. (An IIFE is what you wrote with `(function() {....})();`)
- Angular controllers expose methods and objects through the `$scope` dependency (which you need to inject BTW). If you declare a `var` inside your controller and then try to access it in your HTML, you won't be able to.
- (**EDITED**) Take a look at your `products` array. You don't need the comma at the end of your last key and value -> `soldOut: false,`.

Working code is here: http://plnkr.co/edit/s2397TznhGii84vwSIFA?p=preview

Comment: THanks for spending the time to walk through this with me and help me understand. I want to understand the code, not just get it work. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

This should get you pretty close. Hope it helps :)

```
<html ng-app="gemStore">
<head>
    <title>Angular JS</title>
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="StoreController">

      <h1> {{products.name}} </h1>
      <h1> {{products.price}} </h1>
      <h1> {{products.desc}} </h1>  
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
(function () {

var app = angular.module("gemStore", []);
app.controller('StoreController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.products = gem;
}]);
var gem =
    {
        name:'New Product',
        price:'2.95',
        desc: '...'
    }
})();
```

Comment: @Speed it's always good practice to declare app.js right before the end of the body tag in the html file

Comment: You removed the `ng-repeat` bit

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  mparnisari got me working in a chat. I'll keep your tips in mind as well.

Comment: @Speed You're welcome! can you at least vote my question up :)?

Comment: @mparnisari take a look at your products array... you don't need the comma at the end of your last key and value -> "soldOut: false,". I just thought I should point that out. Happy coding :)